# How to sole preparing authentication request laravel-echo server, could not be authenticated to private-user.1 error

Tags: php, socket.io, radius, laravel-echo, laravel-6

I have an error on laravel echo server, to joining private-user-1

***MYERROR***

```
[3:22:51 PM] - Preparing authentication request to: http://radhakishan.laravel6.com                                                                                       

[3:22:51 PM] - Sending auth request to: http://radhakishan.laravel6.com/broadcasting/auth  

[3:22:52 PM] - sNrKAzpEsjxjnhKwAAAA could not be authenticated to private-user.1{....}  

Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 404
```

I have already installed these packages

1.Package.json  installed packages

```php
"laravel-echo": "^1.6.1",
"pusher-js": "^5.0.2",
"socket.io": "^2.3.0",
"socket.io-client": "^2.3.0"
```

2.Composer.json installed packages

```php
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2",
    "encore/laravel-admin": "^1.7",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
    "predis/predis": "^1.1",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.0"
},
```

3.config/app.php
i have already uncommited

```php
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
```

4.config/broadcasting.php
 i have already set default broadcaster

```php
 'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'redis'),
```

5.routs/channels.php
i have alredy set this

```php
Broadcast::channel('user.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

6.My Event File

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class UserMessage
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
    public $message;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('user.'.$this->message->recever_id);
    }
}
```

7.My controller code

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;
use App\Events\UserMessage;
class HomeController extends Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function messageCreate(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'message' => 'required',
            'recever_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $message = Message::create([
            'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
            'recever_id' => $request->recever_id,
            'message' => $request->message, 
        ]);
        if($message){
            event(new UserMessage($message));
            return ['status'=> true];
        }
        return ['status'=> false];
    }
}
```

8.My blade script code

```
Echo.private('user.{{auth()->user()->id}}')
.listen('PrivateMessage', (e) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```